# move_uploaded_file can't work in PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to move the image from temporary location to some other directory .

The input form is defined as follows:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="rent_details" name="rent_details" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload Image :<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    type:- <select name="spottype" id="spottype">
              <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
              <option value="yyy">yyy</option>
              <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
           </select>
    <input type="submit" id="bidm" name="bidm" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

I have following code for move the file ,

```
$target_dir = "./spotimages/"; 
$tmp_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]; 
$name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$move_to=$target_dir.$name;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $move_to);
```

Here,The files doesn't move spotimages folder. How to solve this. Please help me.

Comment: can you post the form code? or else post the full source code ?

Comment: <form action="#" method="post" id="rent_details" name="rent_details" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload Image :<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
type:- <select name="spottype" id="spottype">
  <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
  <option value="yyy">yyy</option>
  <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
</select> 
<input type="submit" id="bidm" name="bidm" value="Next"/>
</form>

Comment: Ensure your webserver user / group has write permission on the target directory.  if using apache this is usually www-data user & group.

Comment: Check the permission for the folder...

Comment: Please check whether you have the destination folder in the path.. If it exists once check the permissions of the folder..

Comment: I have  spotimages folder and have 777 permissions.

Answer (score 0):

hi did you put this enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

```
<form action="your_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
......
......
......
</form>
```

Comment: then please change your folder permission

Comment: I have 777 permission.